# If statement template in Django

Tags: django, if-statement

I'm trying to create an if-statement to display if event type is online or in person.
if its online then automatically display online, if not its gonna display location

```
<div class='upcoming_events'>
    {% for event in page.get_upcoming_events %}
        <div>
        {{ event.title }}
            <p>
                {{ event.start}} | 
                {% if event_type == Online}
                    Online
                {% elif event_type == "In Person" %}
                    {{ event.location }}
                {% endif %}
            </p>    
                <p><a href="http://www.google.com">Read more</a></p>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

im getting error saying " Invalid block tag on line 54: 'elif', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. "

how can i resolve issue?

Comment: Are you sure is not event.type or event.event_type? Can you add your view class/function so we can see how you are settings up your context data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your first `if`.

Try: `{% if event_type == "Online" %}`

(adding `"` and a missing `%`)

**Edit 1**

If nothing is showing up after this I suggest putting in an `{% else %}` statement to prove that this is falling through the `if` statement.

I don't know your code but from what I can gather you probably also need to change the way you are accessing the `event_type`. If I've read it correctly it should be `event.type` instead.

Comment: Thanks, but after I changed it, nothing would show up. it doesn't display neither location or online

Comment: Yes it does. Right now, its just not display the stuff I want

Comment: Please see my updated answer @Michael - add an `else` and check you are looking at `event.type` correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have to switch to event.type because it wasnt comparing the right stuff